# Find using the Active Directory user who was logged on at last on a computer

Tags: active-directory

We have the problem that sometimes we are looking for a computer and we can’t find it.

So the idea is, to find the last user who was using this computer. I think, that this information should be found in Active Directory.

I searched for this information, but I only could find hints about the activity of users (accounts) but not the information I am looking for.

Does somebody have an idea if this information is in Active Directory? I was not successful using the `ComputerPrincipal` object.

Answer (score 0):

No, this kind of *dynamic* information isn't stored and handled in Active Directory. AD is a pretty *static* repository of user and computer accounts, groups, permissions and so on - but it doesn't keep track of what user has been logged in where and when.